# Why does du give different results?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, du

I use `du` command very often. Recently, I used it to find out 5 heaviest files in root directory of my server, I used the following command:

```
sudo du -ah / | sort -nr | head -n 5
```

Result was:

```
1016K   /var/cache/apt/archives/fonts-dejavu-core_2.35-1_all.deb
1016K   /bin/bash
1008K   /usr/src/linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1052/fs
1008K   /usr/src/linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1049/fs
1004K   /var/awslogs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/ec2/2016-09-15/
```

I then removed -h, and observed an entirely different result:

```
sudo du -a / | sort -nr | head -n 5
```

Result:

```
2551396 /
1189240 /usr
894000  /var
541836  /usr/lib
406276  /var/lib
```

From the `man` page of `du`,

```
-h, --human-readable
              print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

According to my understanding, including or excluding of `-h` should not really cause change in the results, just the size format.

Could you help me understand why this would happen?

Comment: It *does* only change the size format. But `sort -nr` and `head -n 5` will then give you different lines. When you use `du -h` you should use `sort -h`.

Comment: just replace "-n" with "-h" in sort. that should do it: `sudo du -ah / | sort -hr | head -n 5`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1016K` is numerically greater than `2M`. `sort -n` just extracts `1016` and `2`.

Try `sort -h` if your sort supports it.

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` command does not take K/M/G into account, and sorts all "K" before all "M".

Answer (score 0):

Probably whith `-h` your directories' sizes are something like `2G` or `4G`, while files remain `1016K` or `1008K`, and `2` is smaller than `1016` hence directories get sorted out to the end of a list.

Without `-h` total sizes of directories (actually: directory trees) appear clearly greater than sizes of files inside, hence directories are sorted at the top of a list.